# Independent TCP send and receive client in single app

Tags: spring-integration

I coded some programs for TCP client to read write on socket. Those are ok.
My question is that I want to write a client which can send (not required any ack or reply) and a receive (independent of the send).Both needs to communicate to server at same time or simultaneously. 
Is that possible within same connection fatory ?? If I use two connection factories one for send one for receive ??
Can I have some reference document so I can understand TCP send receive work in flow diagram.

Answer (score 0):

See [Collaborating Outbound and Inbound Channel Adapters](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/#ip-collaborating-adapters).

A pair of channel adapters can use the same connection factory to handle arbitrary messaging in both directions.

Comment: Thanks @Gary. One question.. this way it won't pile up message for sender if receiver is getting messages, since both using same connection??

Comment: Yes, sockets are full duplex.